# Slow INSERTs to MEMORY table

Tags: mysql, percona-server

I've been trying to work this issue out, been really killing me! We've been experiencing some slow database queries for a Prestashop installation that we host, and a look into the query log revealed that it is fairly full of simple insert queries like this:

```
INSERT INTO `ps_guest` 
(`id_operating_system`,`id_web_browser`,`id_customer`,`javascript`,
 `screen_resolution_x`,`screen_resolution_y`,`screen_color`,`sun_java`,
 `adobe_flash`,`adobe_director`,`apple_quicktime`,`real_player`,
 `windows_media`,`accept_language`) 
VALUES ('3','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','');
```

Since the data in this table is not something that we need to persist for the long term, we changed the table into a `MEMORY` table.

```
CREATE TABLE `ps_guest` (
  `id_guest` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_operating_system` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_web_browser` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_customer` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `javascript` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `screen_resolution_x` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `screen_resolution_y` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `screen_color` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sun_java` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adobe_flash` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adobe_director` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apple_quicktime` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `real_player` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `windows_media` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accept_language` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_guest`),
  KEY `id_customer` (`id_customer`),
  KEY `id_operating_system` (`id_operating_system`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY AUTO_INCREMENT=188 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

A `MEMORY` table should be fast in theory right? And most of the time it is, but occasionally that same `insert` query **still** shows up in our slow query log.

Since this insert query does block visitor page loads, we hope to minimise/eliminate it completely.

What else should I be looking at? Below is `my.cnf`

```
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
port                           = 3306
server-id                      = 1
user                           = mysql
default_storage_engine         = InnoDB
innodb_doublewrite             = 1
low_priority_updates           = 0
max_write_lock_count           = 1

# MyISAM #
key_buffer_size                = 8M
myisam_recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet             = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000
#skip_name_resolve
#sql_mode                       = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
sql_mode                       = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sysdate_is_now                 = 1
innodb                         = FORCE
innodb_strict_mode             = 1

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/data/

# BINARY LOGGING #
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/data/mysql-bin
expire_logs_days               = 7
sync_binlog                    = 0

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size                 = 32M
max_heap_table_size            = 32M
query_cache_type               = 1
query_cache_size               = 256M
query_cache_limit              = 4M
max_connections                = 40
table_cache                    = 8196
thread_cache_size              = 32
open_files_limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 4096
table_open_cache               = 8196
join_buffer_size               = 4M

# INNODB #
#innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_io_capacity             = 75
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 384M
innodb_log_buffer_size         = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 1536M
innodb_thread_concurrency      = 5

# LOGGING #
log-warnings                   = 2
log_error                      = /var/lib/mysql/data/mysql-error.log
general-log                    = 0
general_log_file               = /var/lib/mysql/data/mysql-general.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
long_query_time                = 3
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/data/mysql-slow.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many rows are in your table, your problem may stem from the `id_customer` and `id_operating_system` indexes.

Try:

```
DROP INDEX `id_customer` ON `ps_guest`;
DROP INDEX `id_operating_system` on `ps_guest`;
CREATE INDEX `id_customer` USING BTREE ON `ps_guest` (`id_customer`);
CREATE INDEX `id_operating_system` USING BTREE ON `ps_guest` (`id_operating_system`);
```

`MEMORY` tables default to creating `HASH` indexes, which work very differently to the indexes on most other MySQL database engines. These can drastically slow queries down, especially when there are indexes with low cardinality (like your `id_operating_system` index).

Peter Zaitsev has shown on the [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/02/01/performance-gotcha-of-mysql-memory-tables/) that this can decrease the speed of queries by more than 100 times.

Unfortunately a `memory` table isn't necessarily fast in theory - there are quite a few caveats.

[MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html) suggests:

> A typical use case for the MEMORY engine involves these characteristics:
>
> - Operations involving transient, non-critical data such as session management or caching. When the MySQL server halts or restarts, the data in MEMORY tables is lost.
> - In-memory storage for fast access and low latency. Data volume can fit entirely in memory without causing the operating system to swap out virtual memory pages.
> - A read-only or read-mostly data access pattern (limited updates).
>
> ...
>
> Despite the in-memory processing for MEMORY tables, they are not necessarily faster than InnoDB tables on a busy server, for general-purpose queries, or under a read/write workload. In particular, the table locking involved with performing updates can slow down concurrent usage of MEMORY tables from multiple sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Use Btree instead of Hash indexes on the memory table and this will solve your problem.

`CREATE INDEX indexname ON yourtable(col1) USING BTREE`

Hash indexes are default for memory tables, they are fast for `SELECT` but slow for `INSERT`.

Comment: i can confirm that this actually yields with ~3x-4x update in insert speed.